# <Wrong number or types of arguments error>Passing parameters to SP within Shell script

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

I am calling an SP within my shell script. Below mentioned are input parameters with their data types being passed through the SP:-

```
p_1 IN VARCHAR2   
p_2 IN VARCHAR2      
p_3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0    
p_4 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'A'    
p_5 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL     
p_6 OUT NUMBER
p_7 OUT VARCHAR2
```

Snippet from my shell script where I pass the variables is as given below:-

```
echo "var p_6 number;" >> $output.txt
echo "var p_7 varchar2(5000);" >> $output.txt

echo "exec call_sp('p_1','p_2',0,'A',null,:p_6,:p_7);" >> $output.txt
echo "exit" >> $output.txt
```

When I execute the shell script, I get the following error in the logs:-

```
BEGIN CALL_SP('1','Art',0 ,'A' ,null ,:p_6,:p_7); END;
  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CALL_SP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Final values being passed to variables are:-

```
p_1 -> '1'
p_2 -> 'Art'
p_3 -> 0
p_4 -> 'A'
p_5 -> null
```

Any help here would be appreciated to quickly fix this error I am getting.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your stored procedure body

Comment: Please show the entire script and the entire generated output.txt file

Comment: Look at `var p_7 varchar2(5000);`: `SP2-0676: Bind variable length cannot exceed 4000`.

Comment: The issue was with my sql developer....it was not using the current procedure with updated parameter set. Thanks all.